# rxjs zip two switchMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

i have define a behaviorSubject:

```
measurementSearchChange$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
this.measurementSearchChange$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(debounceTime(500))
  .pipe(
    switchMap((keyword: string) =>
      this.warningService.getInfluxdbQuery(
        this.selectedMonitorOption,
        'measurement',
        { search_name: keyword }
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.measurementOptions = data;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```

when some action, will do that:

```
this.measurementSearchChange$.next(keyword);
```

it work well now, but i want add a switchMap and zip them so that i can subscribe two different data, like：

```
this.measurementSearchChange$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(debounceTime(500))
  .pipe(
    switchMap((keyword: string) =>
      this.warningService.getInfluxdbQuery(
        this.selectedMonitorOption,
        'measurement',
        { search_name: keyword }
      )
      // another 
      this.warningService.getInfluxdbQuery2(
        this.selectedMonitorOption,
        'measurement2',
        { search_name: keyword }
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((data1: any, data2: any) => {
    this.measurementOptions = data;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```

so how can do that? any help is appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your queries emit a single result and then complete, you can use `forkJoin`, like this:

```ts
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
/* ... */
this.measurementSearchChange$
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap((keyword: string) => forkJoin(
      this.warningService.getInfluxdbQuery(
        this.selectedMonitorOption,
        'measurement',
        { search_name: keyword }
      ),
      this.warningService.getInfluxdbQuery2(
        this.selectedMonitorOption,
        'measurement2',
        { search_name: keyword }
      )
    ))
  )
  .subscribe(([data1, data2]: [any, any]) => {
    this.measurementOptions = data;
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```

If they emit multiple results, use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`.

I wouldn't use `zip`, unless it's the case that the queries can emit more than one result and it's guaranteed that each time one query emits a result the other query will emit one, too.

Comment: It should be forkJoin instead of  Observable.forkJoin?

Comment: @siva636 Yes, it should be. Thanks.